# how can i convert my grails application from http to https under Linux operating system?

Tags: grails

how can i convert my grails application from http to https under Linux operating system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the configuration depends on what container you are running the application in your production environment. You should be [deploying a war](http://www.grails.org/Deployment) to your Production Server not doing a `grails run-app -https`

here is a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602) with a configuration for Tomcat.

I am certain you can google around and find proper configuration based on your application server

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "convert"?

You can run the embedded tomcat with HTTPS enabled by adding -https to the run-app command:

```
grails run-app -https
```

If you want HTTPS enabled in production then you need to configure your app server to support it.

Comment: yes i want HTTPS enabled in production. how can i configure my app server to support it. When i try grails run-app -https a message appear that i can't run app as this way. is there another way

Comment: you shouldn't be using run-app in production. Build a WAR and deploy it. See other answer for a good link