# How do you setup SSL with Grails?

Tags: java, grails, ssl, keystore, keytool

How do you setup SSL with Grails? We have our signed certificate from our provider, and have tried creating a keystore under .grails/1.3.7/ssl/keystore. With just putting our key in, we start grails and get:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledSuites(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:327)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:272)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSESocketFactory.java:742)
```

Maybe we have to import the .crt file with a different command? I used:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias riseup.org.nz -file /etc/ssl/telethon/telethon.crt
```

When I use and alias other than riseup.org.nz, it complains the alias doesn't match the crt.

After running the command, it does ask me if I trust the information, which makes me think of:

> Note: it is not required that you execute a -printcert command prior to importing a certificate, since before adding a certificate to the list of trusted certificates in the keystore, the -import command prints out the certificate information and prompts you to verify it.

from: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html

Comment: The OS is Debian btw, not that that makes too much difference.

Comment: I used this as a starting point, but doesn't quite get me far enough: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602/ssl-tomcat-and-grails>

Comment: Btw, we gave up trying to get it to work with Grails, but my mate setup a pkcs12 key to use with tomcat standalone, but couldn't figure out how to make grails switch from JKS format.

Comment: We now have the working configuration for Tomcat. But from what I understand, you cant point tomcat embedded to an xml config file?