# Grails, SSL, and Controller Actions,  what is the current recommendation

Tags: grails, ssl

I need to have certain URLs (actions) in my app where I receive Credit Card information be SSL/https.  I'm using the new set of Grails security plugins, i.e. Spring Security Core, and Spring Security UI.   These apparently replace the ACEGI security plugin, which I understand had some SSL configuration capabilities at the controller level.

Can you tell me what the current recommendation is for switching to https for certain controllers/actions?  Do I need to resolve everything in Tomcat?

Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602/ssl-tomcat-and-grails

Comment: Yah thanks, I saw that.  But I need to understand down to the controller / action level, making some https and some not.  Also, I have seen references to using the ACEGI plugin for this, but apparently the new security plugins supersede it, yet don't give this type of SSL support.

Comment: edit - see burt's answer -- its right there in the docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See section "17 Channel Security" in the Spring Security Core plugin docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Comment: Thanks Burt, I searched under SSL and didn't find this section -- thanks for pointing it out.   I tried a few maps and had a seemingly strange result: doing  '/member/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
'/**': 'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL' did not work, it created a URL, http://localhost:8080/connect/grails/member/list.dispatch, putting a "grails" in the path.   However, doing a map: '/member/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
'/group/**': 'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL' did work for member , and made the group controller, and all others I tested, insecure, which is what I want. Is the first incorrect?

Comment: I wish comments supported formatting, hopefully it is readable.

Comment: Any time you map `/**` to something you need to consider the implications for every possible url, e.g. it's easy to block access to the favicon with a wildcard rule. Do you really require that non-member URLs be accessed without SSL? It seems like you could just remove that wildcard and only specify that certain patterns require SSL.

Comment: Click the 'help' link when typing your comments - it has examples of the simplified markup syntax allowed in comments.

Comment: Burt - Thanks for your responses.  If I only specify the /member controller as secure, either all of member or a specific action, once I go to it, all other controllers get accessed via https.  It's almost like it switches modes -- something turns https on, and then something must be accessed to turn it back off.  I guess I could cause that to happen -- take the user to a URL that is marked insecure after the secure stuff is done / submitted, e.g. a welcome or thank you page.

Comment: Right, that's expected behavior - once you switch it stays there unless you hit a URL that forces a change abck. Is it a problem to access those URLs with SSL?

Comment: No, not a problem.  I just figure performance will be less, since the server must do more.  So I think taking them back out will work well, since after entering the confidential information, they will hit a submit, and I will know they are done.  Thanks again.