# Web service over SSL in Grails-cxf?

Tags: tomcat, grails, https, cxf, spring-security

I need to serve a specific CXF web service over HTTPS (I have several others that need to work over plain HTTP). In `SecurityConfig.groovy`, I set:

```
httpsPort = 8443
```

and tried both of

```
secureChannelDefinitionSource = '''
   CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
   PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
   /services/doodah/**=REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL
   /**=REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL
'''
```

and

```
channelConfig = [ secure: ['/services/productid/**'], insecure: '/' ]
```

The service stops responding to http protocol at 8080, but doesn't appear to be on https:8443 - at least, telnet connection to 8443 fails.

If I run the app with `grails run-app -https`, all the application works over https.

To separate http from https services, I'll probably need to do this: "[Automatic http/httpS switching with Grails](http://www.juliesoft.com/2010/04/automatic-httphttps-switching-with-grails/)", but for now I'd like at least to get different services running on two different ports.

1. What steps should I follow to have one service working over HTTPS **only**?
2. Looks like there is something else SSL need to work in war, like in this quesion: [SSL, Tomcat and Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602/ssl-tomcat-and-grails)?

My environment is: Grails 1.3.5, acegi-security 0.5.3 (I know it's outdated), Tomcat 6.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's not gonna work with `grails run-app` at all. It looks in `TomcatServer.groovy` in `tomcat` plugin that HTTP and HTTPS startup modes are mutually exclusive. It might work differently way if deployed to a full-blown Tomcat, though, if I add SSL Connector to `server.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Both options in `SecurityConfig.groovy` do work.

In a standalone Tomcat, there's no way to programmatically enable SSL Connector, one has to enable it in global server configuration (`server.xml`): [SSL, Tomcat and Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602/ssl-tomcat-and-grails).

For run-app, I added `scripts/_Events.groovy` with a `eventConfigureTomcat` hook and copied a piece of TomcatServer.groovy in Tomcat plugin:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { Tomcat tomcat ->
    keystore = "./some-keystore"
    keystoreFile = new File(keystore)
    keyPassword = "123456"
    System.setProperty('org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.NotValidating', 'true')

    if (!(keystoreFile.exists())) {
        createSSLCertificate(keystore, keyPassword, keystoreFile)
    }

    def httpsPort = 8443 // TODO: Take from SecurityConfig.groovy

    Connector sslConnector = loadInstance(
        tomcat, 'org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector')
    sslConnector.scheme = "https"
    sslConnector.secure = true
    sslConnector.port = httpsPort
    sslConnector.setProperty("SSLEnabled", "true")
    sslConnector.setAttribute("keystore", keystore)
    sslConnector.setAttribute("keystorePass", keyPassword)
    sslConnector.URIEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    tomcat.service.addConnector sslConnector
}
```

I don't have to do protocol switch trick, Grails correctly redirects between `http` and `https` for me.