# Configuring SSL on embedded Tomcat in a Grails App

Tags: grails, ssl, grails-plugin

I'm running this script to start my Grails 2.0.0 app: **grails -Dserver.host=ei000367 run-app -https**

I want to enable SSL in my application but **I need to use a certificate I generated myself through keytool** and imported it in the grails work directory under ssl/.keystore. I need that certificate because it contains the "correct" name: **CN=ei000367, OU=Test, O=Test** where ei000367 is my machine.

I don't want to use the one autogenerated by grails: CN=localhost, OU=Test, O=Test

It seems like it's possible to configure the tomcat plugin http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat with **tomcat.keystorePath** and **tomcat.keystorePassword** but I am not sure if this is the way to configure the embedded tomcat itself.

In this post [SSL, Tomcat and Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602/ssl-tomcat-and-grails) ataylor seems to have resolved it but I doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks for you patience.

Answer (score 0):

In which format you keystore is?

Java based applications usually expect a JKS (and I recommand to use the same password for the keystore and the private key, most of applications are not able to manage differents password). You can use portecle.sf.net to create a JKS from PEM files.

Comment: First of all say that I'm no expert on certificates. I created a keystore file to store the server's private key and self-signed certificate by executing the following command: %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

Answer (score 0):

For grails 2.5.x, the [Grails Tomcat Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/tomcat) you mentioned specifies these properties, but you are missing the `grails.` prefix in the documentation.

I verified this works locally by adding the following to my `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.tomcat.keyAlias='GrailsApp'
grails.tomcat.keystorePath="/path/to/keystore"
grails.tomcat.keystorePassword="yourPasswordHere"
```