# Grails not listening to https port on production

Tags: grails, ssl, https

I have the following configuration in BuildConfig.groovy: `grails.server.port.https = 8443`

However, when deploying my app (i use AWS OpsWorks) grails does not listen to this port. I see that following messages when grails app finishing load:

```
Sep 08, 2015 1:24:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 08, 2015 1:24:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Sep 08, 2015 1:24:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 67150 ms
```

It tells me that the app is listening for http requests on port 8080 but i don't see anything regarding https. What should i do to make my grails app receive https requests?

Comment: how do you run ? which grails version ? one way is to run `grails run-app -https`

Comment: I am building with prod war and deploying to an Amazon server with Tomcat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364602/ssl-tomcat-and-grails

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you used in the BuildConfig.groovy is used to run application using command `grails run-app -https`.

Since you are creating war for production and deploying the war in external tomcat, you need to configure the tomcat to listen https requests. In order to configure tomcat for https, please go through [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)

**The detail about the configuration you used is :**

In order to run application in https locally, we use command

> grails run-app -https

This runs the application in port 8443 by default. There are two ways to change the port number.

1. One way is as you did above in BuildConfig.groovy by adding `grails.server.port.https = 8443`
2. Another way is to run application with command `grails -Dserver.port=8443 run-app -https`

You can change the port number to any like 8993.